# Regex ignore nested matched

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to parse nested data types.

Examples:

`ARRAY<STRING>`, `MAP<STRING, INTEGER>`.

When I have an array, I use that regex `^ARRAY<(.*)>$`. Regex returns one group with a data type.

When I have a map, I use that regex `^MAP<(.*),(.*)>$`. Regex returns two groups - first key data type and second value data type.

But it does not work when I have Map as a key/value in another Map.

Examples:

`MAP<MAP<STRING, STRING>, STRING>` The result should be `MAP<STRING, STRING>` and `STRING`

`ARRAY<MAP<ARRAY<STRING>, MAP<STRING, INTEGER>>>` The result should be `MAP<ARRAY<STRING>, MAP<STRING, INTEGER>>`

Is it possible to ignore nested matches? If yes - how?

Comment: Regular expressions are not really good at dealing with nested brackets like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the variant of regex, you can create a sort of pseudo parser using [named subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#define). For example, this one works with PHP's PCRE variant:

```
/
(?(DEFINE)
   (?<TYPE> STRING | INTEGER | MAP<(?&TYPE),(?&TYPE)> | ARRAY<(?&TYPE)>))
^(?&TYPE)$
/x
```

The syntax varies based on the language, so you'd need to look it up.